# displaying pdf in xamarin android

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin

I am trying to create an app that will be able to display a pdf file in the app itself. I'm currently using the Xamarin.Bindings.PDFView-Android by SIDOVSKY which works really nicely. I can open a file easily from the assets... what I'm struggling to do is open a file from the internet.

Just a single line of code:

```
FindViewById<PDFView>(Resource.Id.pdf_view).FromAsset("report.pdf").Show();
```

Is enough to display a PDF that can be pinched to zoom which is great. However, I now want to access a file stored on the local network. Either using a SMB share, or through the intranet. Whichever way I try I can't figure it out.

There is a .FromFile setting, but I can't get it to work by putting a smb path in here. Is there a way to convert this? Or must I download the file to the local device first?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: you will need to copy/download the file from the network location to local storage first

Comment: any tips how to do this? I'd rather access through samba if possible. I'm trying to use ezsmb, but I can't figure out how to copy the file. The move command just seems to be on the server, I need to move to local storage.

Comment: You can use the pddf.js and the webview to display the pdf which is on the internet in your application.[link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) In addition, you can use the Storm.AndroidPdfViewer package to display the pdf which is on the local network.[link](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)